# Replace output in a loop in bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have a few little scripts that I use for monitoring some aspects of our application that reside in an infinite loop with a 3 second sleep and simply display the output of `ps aux | grep -i app_name` or `mysql -e "SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G"` just so I can easily watch for a few mins without hitting any keys, what I'd like to know is how I could 'refresh' the values on the screen instead of appending to them, I guess the best example I have is of top, it refreshes values instead of continuously printing to the screen.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can include the "clear" command in your loop (without looking at your code)

Comment: Argh, so easy! Works beautifully, thanks! (I feel so silly!) :)

Comment: but it would clear the entire screen.. isn't there a way to delete a line on stdout just like using \b in C

Answer (score 5):

Try [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) utility. It runs arbitrary command in configurable interval (-n flag). It also can highlight differences in output between refreshes (-d flag).

Comment: Great work. watch is very cool, never knew about it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 
 echo -n -e "\b" to undo your previous output together with echo -n "output" to maintain your new output on the cleared line

Answer (score 0):

The probably simplest way:

```
watch -n 3 'ps aux | grep -i app_name'
```